# How to implement numpy-style indexing in own array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For some purpose, I am maintaining an array-class, call it `A`. Since `A` is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for numpy-arrays, it should have the same interface (at least for my needs). Now, the problem comes with everything that involves indexing, so in particular the methods `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`. Consider, e.g., `__setitem__(self, key, value)`. Now, numpy's broadcasting covers quite some cases: key can be a tuple whose entries are...

- integers
- lists of integers
- lists of integer tuples
- boolean arrays of matching size
- ...

mixed nicely together. Additionally, indexing should adhere to numpy's broadcasting mechanism. At the moment, I am covering only the cases I need, but all these distinctions, mostly covered using `isinstance`, are annoying to maintain.

Is there any better way?

Comment: numpy "broadcasting" refers to something else: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html ; you more likely mean numpy indexing and slicing syntax (?)

Comment: maybe [functools.singledispatchmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod) can help you out with that

Comment: @Demi-Lune, though the broadcasting rules do apply when using several arrays (or lists) as indices for different dimensions.  OP, `numpy` broadcasting depends heavily on the use of `strides`  For example play around with `np.broadcast_arrays`. The actual code is deeply embedded in the `numpy` sources.

Comment: I suspect you have given yourself too big of a task.  `numpy` indexing depends heavily on its `strided` multidimensional implementation, which involves a large `c` code source.  It would be a lot of work to reverse-engineer this.

Comment: @Demi-Lune You're right, this is not (only) about broaadcasting but also numpy-style indexing in general.

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing exactly what your object is. I guess we know it is array-like, but depending on how you store the elements, it's hard to say how you should implement indexing.

Comment: As for making a drop-in substitute `ndarray`, here's a couple of sources: 1) subclassing `ndarray` (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.subclassing.html), 2) array-like classes (https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.dispatch.html). Both take some work to truly emulate numpy arrays, but not that's not really surprising for reimplementing hundreds of functions for a new type.